# CSS Align header with menu inside

Tags: html, css, menu, header

Hi im just starting out and i have a small problem, for some reason i cant get the header and the menuholder to align, the menuholder appears slightly below the header, i need it to be inside the header

```
#header {

    max-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/bgpattern.png) repeat-x;
    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgb(139, 141, 143);
    z-index: 5;


}

#menuholder {

    height:50px;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Share your HTML

Comment: please share your html on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: put is to jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you have in mind?

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="menuholder">
        This is my menu
    </div>
</div>

#header {
    max-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/bgpattern.png) repeat-x;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgb(139, 141, 143);
}
#menuholder {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```